# How to use newline (\n) within another function (print(len(VAR))) to let this output start in a new line?

Tags: newline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi5tA.png)

how to start new line when using another function to get the processed output but not only using the print
function to start new line. Also, how to add print words after the len function since using the + shows
a traceback error.

Comment: Canu use template literals?

Comment: [**We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please post all text into the question with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Questions with images of text/code/errors are routinely closed. Please also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure this & your future questions are suitable for this Q&A.

Comment: Remember to always tag your question with the language you are using -- [tag:python] in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Where you want to print something, add '\n', this gives one line. For example,

```
string text = "\n\n\nHello there";
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

this code puts 3 emty lines.
(If this is not what you want, could you try to describe your problem clearly)